# Django debug toolbar on a remote server

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I have just installed django debug toolbar locally to test my django app and it works great.

I've just committed and pushed with mercurial the new changes on my test remote server and I can't see the toolbar. The files are the same.

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If DEBUG is True and you are not seeing the toolbar, then you probably need to add the IP address of the computer you are accessing the site from to [`INTERNAL_IPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#internal-ips) in your `settings.py` file.

```
INTERNAL_IPS = (<your_ip_address>,)
```